# Run a docker with specific ip address

Tags: docker

I am running a few Docker containers from my computer and they are linked from one to another like this:

Running the db docker container:

```
docker run -d -p 27019:27017 --name=docker-db1 docker_db
```

Running the app container:

```
docker run -d \
    --publish=$PORT:80 \
    --link=docker-db1:docker_db \
    --hostname="docker-$APPNAME" \
    --name=app-web \
    abernix/meteord:base
```

Is there a way to define an IP address for Docker to run on 
the same way I define the hostname?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Through the docker daemon

You first need to create a network:

`docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 network_name`

Then, when running a container, you can specify an IP address for it with the flags:

`--net network_name --ip 172.18.0.XX`

#### With docker-compose

As requested, I provide an example of static predefined IPs using docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
    myservice:
        build: .
        networks:
            mynet:
                ipv4_address: 172.25.0.XX

networks:
    mynet:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
              - subnet: 172.25.0.0/24
```

Comment: how can do the same in docker-compose?

Comment: what does the 'X' in the ipv4_address stand for?

Comment: @fay Oh, I mean with it that you can put whatever number you like there.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the "whatever number you like" in an update to this answer? I've done a lot of [reading on this](https://4sysops.com/archives/windows-container-networking-part-1-configuring-nat/) and think I know what you mean. A concrete example would be nice, however

Comment: To clarify, I'm largely a network newb. I know "whatever you like" can mean 0-255, but I didn't know if the subnet declaration limited your specific choice in some way.

Comment: @bkwdesign with "--subnet=172.18.0.0/16", the /16 or slash-16 is CIDR notation which means the last 2 address segments can be anything you want.